# WCF REST cache list depending on id

Tags: c#, wcf, caching

I have walk through this Microsoft document [Caching Support for WCF Web HTTP Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443(v=vs.100).aspx) and I have managed to create a caching for a list of users.
This is how it looks:

```
public List<ForJson.User> UserList()
{
    bool nil;
    WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.CheckConditionalRetrieve(this.idGenerator.GetId(this.usersEtag, out nil));
    var userList = this.UnitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAll()
        .Result.Select(u => new ForJson.User
        {
            FirstName = u.FirstName,
            LastName = u.LastName,
            UserId = u.UserId,
            CardNumber = u.CardNumber
        })
        .ToList();
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetETag(this.idGenerator.GetId(this.usersEtag, out nil));
    return userList;
}
```

I also wanted to implement this for list of Assets for specific User, but with no luck. I find it difficult to understand what am I doing wrong. If someone could point me the mistakes:

```
public List<ForJson.Asset> AssetList(int? userId)
{
    bool nil;
    List<ForJson.Asset> assetList;
    if (userId != null)
    {
        if (!this.assetEtag.TryGetValue(userId.Value, out object eTag))
        {
            eTag = new object();
            this.assetEtag.Add(userId.Value, eTag);
        }
        WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.CheckConditionalRetrieve(this.idGenerator.GetId(eTag, out nil));
        assetList = this.UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(userId.Value)
            .Result.Assets.Select(a => new ForJson.Asset
            {
                AssetId = a.AssetId,
                Barcode = a.Barcode,
                Type = a.Type.Name,
                UserId = userId.Value
            })
            .ToList();
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetETag(this.idGenerator.GetId(eTag, out nil));
        return assetList;
    }
    WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.CheckConditionalRetrieve(this.idGenerator.GetId(this.assetEtag, out nil));
    assetList = this.UnitOfWork.AssetRepository.Find(a => a.UserId == null)
        .Result.Select(a => new ForJson.Asset
        {
            AssetId = a.AssetId,
            Barcode = a.Barcode,
            Type = a.Type.Name
        })
        .ToList();
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetETag(this.idGenerator.GetId(this.assetEtag, out nil));
    return assetList;
}
```

How is this working right now? Like it doesn't take userId in account in next method calls. When first call for is with userId then for next 5 minutes it returns assets for this user (regardless of user being null or any other id)

```
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="CacheFor5Minutes" duration="300" varyByParam="none" sqlDependency="AssetsSystem:Users;AssetsSystem:Assets"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "userList")]
[AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor5Minutes")]
List<ForJson.User> UserList();

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
    UriTemplate = "assetList?userId={userId}")]
[AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor5Minutes")]
List<ForJson.Asset> AssetList(int? userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The soultion was to add `userId` as `veryByParam` in `web.config`

```
<add name="CacheFor5MinutesByUser" duration="300" varyByParam="userId" sqlDependency="AssetsSystem:Users;AssetsSystem:Assets"/>
```